# Loop over groupby columns in r and apply a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello everyone I would need help in order to loop over a dataframe by groups of columns.

Here is an example of dataframe

```
  Group       Species Values
1    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val1
2    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val2
3    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val3
4    G2   Canis_lupus   Val4
5    G2   Canis_lupus   Val5
6    G3  Griseus_lupa   Val6
7    G4  Griseus_lupa   Val7
```

I would like to :

1 - loop over `c(df$Group,df$Species)`

2 - take the `df$Values` and store it as a `vector`

3 - put that vector into a function called `afunction`

4 - open a `treefile` with `anotherfunction` where its name is the `df$Group name`

5 - get the `output value` of that function and add it into a `new_column`

So here is an exemple of what the code should do :

first groups is `G1,Cattus_cattus` :

```
  Group       Species Values
1    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val1
2    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val2
3    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val3
```

Then I open the `treefile` with `treefile <- anotherfunction(G1)`

Then I generate the output value such as `output_value<-afunction(treefile,c("Val1","Val2","Val3))`

then the `output_value = 30`

so I add 30 into the df :

```
  Group       Species Values new_column
1    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val1 30
2    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val2 30
3    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val3 30
```

if there is only one row within the Group, then I do nothing and add a NA.

Note that of course it is a nonexisting function, so you cannot reproduce the exemple.

Ath the and we should get something like (where `new_column` values are random here).

```
  Group       Species Values new_column
1    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val1 30
2    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val2 30
3    G1 Cattus_cattus   Val3 30
4    G2   Canis_lupus   Val4 21
5    G2   Canis_lupus   Val5 21
6    G3  Griseus_lupa   Val6 NA
7    G4  Griseus_lupa   Val7 NA
```

Does someone have an idea please?
So fare I known how to loop over a dataframe using a for loop but here I do not known how to deal with groups composed of 2 colums..

**data**

```
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Canis_lupus", "Cattus_cattus", 
"Griseus_lupa"), class = "factor"), Values = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Val1", 
"Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5", "Val6", "Val7"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(treefile = anotherfunction(first(Group)), 
            Values = list(Values)) %>%
  mutate(new_column = map2_dbl(treefile, Values, afunction))
```

This would give you a summarised dataframe. To get the same number of rows back you can `left_join` with `df` by `Group`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

```
anotherfunction = function(x){
  #do something with your treefile
  ifelse("Val2" %in% x, 30, ifelse("Val4" %in% x, 21, NA))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(new_column=anotherfunction(Values))
```

You did not give a lot of information about `anotherfunction()` so I used an ugly nested `ifelse()` to mimic the behavior.

The key is that `mutate()` will use the Values inside the Groups.

To explore this, you can try to run the code:

```
anotherfunction = function(x){browser()}
```